# React setState doesn't update the state after submitting input form

Tags: reactjs

I am new in React and want to develop easy app - there is input field from which I want to take values and render list. After added option in text field I want to update this list whith new option. 
setState function does not work and I don't know how to connect input submit and list rendering. My code is below.

WaterApp.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import AddWater from './AddWater';
    import WaterElements from './WaterElements';

    export default class WaterApp extends React.Component {
        state = {
            quantities: ['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc']
        };

handleAddQuantity = (quantity) => {
    this.setState(() => ({
        quantities: ['ddddd', 'eeeee']
    }));
    console.log('works');
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <WaterElements quantities={this.state.quantities} />
            <AddWater handleAddQuantity={this.handleAddQuantity} />
        </div>
    )
}
    }
```

AddWater.js

```
    import React from 'react';

    export default class AddWater extends React.Component {
        handleAddQuantity = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const quantity = e.target.elements.quantity.value;
            console.log(quantity);
};
render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleAddQuantity}>
            <input type="text" name="quantity" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    )            
}
    }
```

WaterElements.js

```
    import React from 'react';

    const WaterElements = (props) => (
<div>
    <p>Water Quantity:</p>
    {
        props.quantities.map((quantity) => 
            <p key={quantity}>{quantity}</p>
        )
    }
</div>
    );

    export default WaterElements;
```

I expect list to be ddddd, eeeee at this moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never calling `props.handleAddQuantity`

```
export default class AddWater extends React.Component {
    handleAddQuantity = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const quantity = e.target.elements.quantity.value;
        props.handleAddQuantity(quantity)
};
render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleAddQuantity}>
            <input type="text" name="quantity" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    )            
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed my AddWater.js to this: 
```import React from 'react';

export default class AddWater extends React.Component {
    handleAddQuantity = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const quantity = e.target.elements.quantity.value;
        console.log(quantity);
        this.props.handleAddQuantity(quantity);
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleAddQuantity}>
                <input type="text" name="quantity" />
                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
        )            
    }
}```

Comment: You're welcome. Consider accept the answer to close it

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setState(() => ({
    quantities: ['ddddd', 'eeeee']
}));
```

should be

```
this.setState({
    quantities: ['ddddd', 'eeeee']
});
```

and after for add

```
this.setState({
    quantities: [...state.quantities, quantity]
});
```

Comment: Isn't wrong  to do this: `setState(() => ({prop : value}))`, you're just using the `updater` version without declaring `prevState`arg

Answer (score 0):

to update use this format

```
this.state({key:value});
not  this.state(()=>{key:value});

handleAddQuantity = (quantity) => {
    this.setState({
        quantities: ['ddddd', 'eeeee']
    }));
    console.log('works');
}
```